# SQL Server: Iterate through dates and prices to get a start date and stop date

Tags: sql-server

Forgive me if my question is unclear. Having difficulty putting it into words.

So, I have pricing information(example screenshot included) where I need to have a start and stop date for a particular price. 
My variables are: 
SFITM: short item part number,
SFLITM: long item part number(should be consistent and distinct with SFITM),
SFDATE: date that price is active,
SFMMTL: price on row SFDATE.
In the example, I've included in my query a row_number() partition (over sflitm order by sflitm, sfdate) as RowRank.

This is production data so the price may repeat on the next line.
What I'm looking to do is return the initial start date of a price(will be number 1 in "RowRank" column and the SFDATE as "StartDate". Then if the price changed on the next row in the series(per the SFLITM column) and "RowRank" being 1 + x then the date will be the SFDATE(of next row) - 1 as the "EndDate" with the respective price(SFMMTL). The next row per the SFLITM(if the same) with a different price(SFMMTL) will iterate having the SFDATE as the "StartDate" and "EndDate"  will be, as before, SFDATE -1.

Current Script:

select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sflitm order by sflitm,sfdate) as RowRank,x.*
from
(
select distinct sfitm, sflitm,sfdate,sfmmtl
from vInvoiced where sfitm <> 0

) x

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ORvP.png)

[Desired Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbEcr.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Made the edits..sorry for the flummux

Comment: give us the raw data and expected output if possible in sqlfiddle.com or rextester.com ....